# ASP.Net Login redirect using DestinationPageUrl

Tags: asp.net, forms, redirect, authentication

I have created a login form and I'm trying to redirect the user to the admin panel if login is successful. In PHP I used to redirect it just like you would do with Response.Redirect() in ASP.Net however I see the login form has a DestinationPageUrl property. How do I trigger this one if login is successful? I'm using MySQL.

Here's my code for the login event:

```
        protected void loginform_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = loginform.UserName.ToString();
        string password = loginform.Password.ToString();
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        Regex rg = new Regex("^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        {
            errors.Add("Username is empty\n");
        }
        else if (!rg.IsMatch(username))
        {
            errors.Add("Username can only contain alphanumeric letters, - and _\n");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
        {
            errors.Add("Password is empty\n");
        }

        string queryRows = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
        Database db = new Database();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryRows, db.getCon());

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", password);
        db.Open();
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        db.Close();

        int numRows = 0;

        if (result != null)
        {
            numRows = Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }

        if (numRows > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/admin/Admin.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            loginform.FailureText = "<br /><br />User credentials are invalid.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> The DestinationPageUrl property specifies the page that is displayed when a
> ```
>
> login attempt is successful. The default behavior of the Login control is to return the user to the referring page, or to the page defined in the defaultUrl attribute of the forms element in the Web.config file.

Jus go through this link for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.destinationpageurl.aspx